# How to wait async/await finishes in the loop and go to the next iteration?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, async-await

In the nested loops I have async await.
For me it is important that on each iteration loop will wait until await will be finished/data received and the start next iteration.

```
const _sampleFilters = async (
  pageName,
  details,
  available,
) => {
  for (const filterName of Object.keys(details)) {
    for (const filterValue of Object.keys(details[filterName])) {
      const data = (await fetchDetails(
        pageName
      ));

      details[filterName][filterValue].allDetails = cloneDeep(
        getProcessedData(
          data.map(data => data.value),
          available,
          pageName,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: The `for ... of` loop should work, try opening a new question about that

Comment: Dear @CristianTraìna
I tried this one, but also does not help

const _sampleFilters = async (
  pageName,
  details,
  available,
) => {
  for (const filterName of Object.keys(details)) {
    for (const filterValue of Object.keys(details[filterName])) {
      const data = (await fetchDetails(
        pageName
      ));

      details[filterName][filterValue].allDetails = cloneDeep(
        getProcessedData(
          data.map(data => data.value),
          available,
          pageName,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
};

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71152670/why-in-the-nested-loops-await-not-wait