# Why in the nested loops await not wait?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, async-await

In the nested loops I have async await. For me it is important that on each iteration loop will wait until await will be finished/data received and the start next iteration.
Also this method used in the another loop.

```
const _sampleFilters = async (
  pageName,
  details,
  available,
) => {
  for (const filterName of Object.keys(details)) {
    for (const filterValue of Object.keys(details[filterName])) {
      const data = (await fetchDetails(
        pageName
      ));

      details[filterName][filterValue].allDetails = cloneDeep(
        getProcessedData(
          data.map(data => data.value),
          available,
          pageName,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
};
```

```
for (const item of items) {
   _sampleFilters();
}
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question what the problem is

Comment: Dear @Phil
The problem is that loops are finished but I have not received values for awaits
For example
const data = (await fetchDetails(
        pageName
      ));
Loops are finished and after several seconds I receive the values for const data

Comment: In you second block of code, you aren't passing any arguments to `_sampleFilters()` but it requires 3. You are also not awaiting each call but it's not clear from your question whether or not that's important

Answer (score 0):

Use await in your outermost loop. For example

```
async function foo()
{
    for (const item of items) {
       await _sampleFilters();
    }
}

foo();
```